# Tokenizing sentences with unnest_tokens(), ignoring abbreviations

Tags: r, text, tidytext

I'm using the excellent `tidytext` package to tokenize sentences in several paragraphs. For instance, I want to take the following paragraph:

> "I am perfectly convinced by it that Mr. Darcy has no defect. He owns it himself without disguise."

and tokenize it into the two sentences

1. "I am perfectly convinced by it that Mr. Darcy has no defect."
2. "He owns it himself without disguise."

However, when I use the default sentence tokenizer of `tidytext` I get three sentences.

**Code**

```
df <- data_frame(Example_Text = c("I am perfectly convinced by it that Mr. Darcy has no defect. He owns it himself without disguise."))


unnest_tokens(df, input = "Example_Text", output = "Sentence", token = "sentences")
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
                              Sentence
                                <chr>
1 i am perfectly convinced by it that mr.
2                    darcy has no defect.
3    he owns it himself without disguise.
```

What is a simple way to use `tidytext` to tokenize sentences but without running into issues with common abbreviations such as "Mr." or "Dr." being interpreted as sentence endings?

Comment: There are great answers below. Just for clarity, the default tokenizing in tidytext comes from the tokenizers package, and you can see how the sentence tokenizing is implemented here: https://github.com/ropensci/tokenizers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex as splitting condition, but there is no guarantee that this would include all common hororifics:

```
unnest_tokens(df, input = "Example_Text", output = "Sentence", token = "regex",
              pattern = "(?<!\\b\\p{L}r)\\.")
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
                                                     Sentence
                                                        <chr>
1 i am perfectly convinced by it that mr. darcy has no defect
2                         he owns it himself without disguise
```

You can of course always create your own list of common titles, and create a regex based on that list:

```
titles =  c("Mr", "Dr", "Mrs", "Ms", "Sr", "Jr")
regex = paste0("(?<!\\b(", paste(titles, collapse = "|"), "))\\.")
# > regex
# [1] "(?<!\\b(Mr|Dr|Mrs|Ms|Sr|Jr))\\."

unnest_tokens(df, input = "Example_Text", output = "Sentence", token = "regex",
              pattern = regex)
```

Comment: This solution unfortunately breaks for sentences ending in "quotes." (In American typography we put the closing punctuation inside the quote.) That may or may not matter if you are stripping out punctuation.

Answer (score 5):

Both *corpus* and *quanteda* have special handling for abbreviations when determining sentence boundaries. Here's how to split sentences with *corpus*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(corpus)
df <- data_frame(Example_Text = c("I am perfectly convinced by it that Mr. Darcy has no defect. He owns it himself without disguise."))

text_split(df$Example_Text, "sentences")
##   parent index text                                                         
## 1 1          1 I am perfectly convinced by it that Mr. Darcy has no defect. 
## 2 1          2 He owns it himself without disguise.
```

If you want to stick with `unnest_tokens`, but want a more exhaustive list of English abbreviations, you can follow @useR's advice but use the *corpus* abbreviation list (most of which were taken from the Common Locale Data Repository):

```
abbrevations_en
##  [1] "A."       "A.D."     "a.m."     "A.M."     "A.S."     "AA."       
##  [7] "AB."      "Abs."     "AD."      "Adj."     "Adv."     "Alt."    
## [13] "Approx."  "Apr."     "Aug."     "B."       "B.V."     "C."      
## [19] "C.F."     "C.O.D."   "Capt."    "Card."    "cf."      "Col."    
## [25] "Comm."    "Conn."    "Cont."    "D."       "D.A."     "D.C."    
## (etc., 155 total)
```